# is possible to execute commands on host from snap package?

Tags: command-line, snap, process

I am building snap from command line program to guess linux commands from natural language. For example `cal` for `show calendar`. When command is proposed I need to confirm them by `Enter`. So after `Enter` I expect to execute `cal` on my host system.

I works when program is executed natively on host machine thanks to the following code:

```rust
let mut child = Command::new(command_name)
  .args(command_args)
  .stdin(Stdio::inherit())
  .stdout(Stdio::inherit())
  .stderr(Stdio::inherit())
  .spawn()
  .expect("Failed to execute command");
```

but when i packaged this app into `snap` i seen error:

```bash
➜ gpt-cli show calendar
> Execute.:

cal

 Yes
thread 'main' panicked at 'Failed to execute command: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }', src/main.rs:126:26
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

I afraid that `cal` is not available on `snap container` and my program does not have access to host context.

So question is: **can i give access to snap app to execute programs on host?**

I was checking [interfaces](https://snapcraft.io/docs/supported-interfaces) but not found nothing connected with access to host programs.

[snapcraft.yaml](https://github.com/gustawdaniel/gpt-cli/blob/18-snap/snapcraft.yaml)

---

#### Update

I found solution:

Firstly I needed `process-control`

```yaml
apps:
  gpt-cli:
    command: gpt-cli
    plugs:
      - process-control
      - network
      - network-bind
```

and

```
confinement: classic
```

Comment: Classic confinement (https://snapcraft.io/docs/classic-confinement) allows for it, but its not easy to get *classic* defined apps into the store given they have full system access.

Comment: I found 'process-control' and `confinement: classic`. I will try this way and potentially ask canonical team about alternatives. You can post it as answer because it solved problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classic confinement (https://snapcraft.io/docs/classic-confinement) allows for it, but it's not easy to get *classic* defined apps into the store given they have full system access.

> Classic confinement is a permissive Snap confinement level, equivalent
> to the full system access that traditionally packaged applications
> have.
>
> It’s often used as a stop-gap measure to enable developers to publish
> applications that need more access than the current set of interfaces
> and permissions allow.